# Parsing multiline ini like file using PCRE regex

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have an ini like file where we have list of `<key> = <value>` items. What complicates things is that some values are multiline and can contain `=` character (tls private key).
Example:

```
groupid = foo
location = westus
randomkey = fbae3700c34cb06c
resourcename = example4-resourcegroup
tls_private_key = -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
//stuff
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

foo = 123
faa = 223
```

What I have so far for pattern is this `/^(.*?)\ \=\ (.*[^=]*)$/m` and it works for all keys except the tls_private_key because it contains `=` so it only fetches partial value.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might match all the values over mulitple lines, asserting that the next line does not contain a space equals sign space:

```
^(.*?) = (.*(?:\R(?!.*? = ).*)*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/S4WBSY/1)

If the key can not have spaces:

```
^([^\s=]+)\h+=\h+(.*(?:\R(?![^\s=]+\h+=\h+).*)*)$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `([^\s=]+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ chars other than `=` or a whitespace char
- `\h+=\h+` Match an `=` between spaces
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `.*` Match the whole line
  - `(?:\R(?![^\s=]+\h+=\h+).*)*` Repeat all following lines that do not contain a space = space
- `)` Close capture group 2
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vtuzuP/1)

Answer (score 4):

You may use this regex with a lookahead:

```sh
^\h*(?<key>[\w-]+)\h*=\h*(?<value>[\s\S]*?)(?=\R\h*[\w-]+\h*=|\z)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4GVupf/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^` Start a line
- `\h*`: 0 or more horizontal whitespaces
- `(?<key>[\w-]+)`: Group `key` that matches 1+ word characters or hyphens
- `\h*`: 0 or more horizontal whitespaces
- `=`: Match a `=`
- `\h*`: 0 or more horizontal whitespaces
- `(?<value>[\s\S]*?)`: Group `value` that matches 0 or more of any characters **including newlines**
- `(?=\R\h*[\w-]+\h*=|\z)`: Lookahead to assert that at next position we have a line break followed by key and `=` or there is end of input

Answer (score 0):

Another variation:

```php
(?sm)^([^=\n]*)\s=\s(.*?)(?=\n[^=\n]*\s=\s|\z)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/FQ0Uqe/1)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?ms)                    set flags for this block (with ^ and $
                           matching start and end of line) (with .
                           matching \n) (case-sensitive) (matching
                           whitespace and # normally)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^=\n]*                  any character except: '=', '\n'
                             (newline) (0 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  =                        '='
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character (0 or more times (matching
                             the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \n                       '\n' (newline)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^=\n]*                  any character except: '=', '\n'
                             (newline) (0 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    =                        '='
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \z                       the end of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```